# Set Style Trigger in Accordion ContentItem and Modify Container Property WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to set a property value of an Accordion Container when the mouse is directly over on an Item of a AccordionItem.

This code modifies the own property, but I would like to modify the container's property.

```
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="#2ebdff" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
```

Here is the visual example:

[image]

[image]